# Multiplying numbers in C

Tags: c, types, printf, specifier

I have written the following code to multiply two numbers and I see the result to be incorrect. I assume the data type is not holding the value right. But the answer its printing is incorrect.

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
    long int val1,val2;
    val1=val2=1235;
    char c = 'y';
    switch(c)
    {
        case 'y' : printf("%20d",val1*val2);
            break;
        default: printf("invalid");
            break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**OUTPUT :**
17897 //which is not the right answer
//it should actually be 1525225

Comment: I don't see any C++ here.

Comment: You should mention what toolchain you're using - it appears to be for a 16-bit target.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Data type is holding the right value but you are using the wrong specifier. You should use `%ld` with long int.

`printf("%20ld",val1*val2);`

I double checked and it worked.

Comment: I get the output as 1789715428

Comment: @Koneri what compiler are you using for this?

Comment: Not sure i was using DosBox C++ compiler